# print white space instead of zero for 2D int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, pascals-triangle

I am trying to print pascal's triangle using 2D int array

And printing 2D array in below way

```
public static void pascal (int n)
     { 
        int[][] pascalArray = new int[n][n];

        // Code here

        }

        printArray(pascalArray);

    public static void printArray(int[][] array)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
         {
             for(int j=0; j<array[i].length;j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
```

For n =4

I am getting below output

```
Enter rows in the Pascal's triangle (or 0 to quit): 4
1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 
1 2 1 0 
1 3 3 1
```

Now I want white-space instead of zero or an isosceles triangle format for pretty print

Is that possible in for 2D **int** array
or can we change 2D int array into some string array in *printArray* method and achieve the same?

I tried system.out.format but some how I am unable to get the output because of int 2D array

Comment: You could just have a check in your loop that checks to see if it's zero, and if it is, print a space instead of a 0.

Comment: @EvanLaHurd

i tried if (array[i][j]==0)
        array[i][j]= ' ';

But array is int 2D and it is unable to assign white space , I tried unicode also but still not showing the way I want.

Comment: Don't assign the space to `array[i][j]`, just use `System.out.print("  ");`

Comment: Thanks for input .. but  some how I am getting 

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for doing that!!!

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong...if you're only adding a check for 0 and printing a space instead of 0, then it shouldn't do that if it already wasn't. Either way, Andy's answer is your best bet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you want a triangle, and you know the array is square, you could simply change the upper bound of the inner loop.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
         for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
         {
             System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
```

Comment: Oh yes!!!! I didn't think that way... thanks for the info man... It seems I made a newbie mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

You may just add the instruction that I added below. It prints only if the value in the array is not equal to "0". If it's a String array, use the `equals()` method

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 {
     for(int j=0; j<array[i].length;j++)
     {
         if (array[i][j] != 0) System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```